# How to make left and right Grid sticky, and Middle one scrollable in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, fixed, sticky

I am using Bootstrap 4 for Website Homepage.
I have used 3 grids, col-md-3, col-md-6, col-md-3.
I want 1st and last grid to be sticky on Position and middle to be scrollable.

```
            <div class="col-lg-3 d-none d-md-block">
               //want sticky on fixed left position
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
               //all contents in middle scrollable
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 d-none d-md-block">
              //want sticky on fixed right position
            </div>
```

[image: View Image description here]

[Check code here](https://codepen.io/vandana-ghadge/pen/yLLwvKK)

Comment: Set the left and right section ul to `position:fixed` and then fix the design issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simplest** way is to use the Bootstrap `sticky-top` class.

```
<div class="container" style="position:relative; margin-top:100px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 d-none d-md-block">
            <ul class="list-group shadow bg-white rounded sticky-top">
                ..
            </ul>
            <hr class="d-sm-none">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card shadow bg-white rounded">
                //
            </div>
            <hr class="d-sm-none">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 d-none d-md-block">
            <ul class="list-group shadow bg-white rounded sticky-top">
                ..
            </ul>
            <hr class="d-sm-none">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/AUtPqy2GY2

***EDIT***

If there is something else (like a navbar or header) above the sticky items, override the `top` of `sticky-top` class accordingly to offset the height...

```
.sticky-top {
    top: 100px; /* height of header */
}
```

Comment: my header is already on top.. using sticky top its overriding on my header

Comment: I am so sorry for inconvenience.. i haven't added it on codepen.. I have just uploaded my header within code you can check it now,. https://codepen.io/vandana-ghadge/pen/yLLwvKK

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer and [the codeply](https://codeply.com/p/AUtPqy2GY2)

Answer (score 1):

Add scroll in middle section rather then position `fixed` to 2 elements as it create problem and extra overridden style in responsive.

Updated HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="fixed">
         //all contents in middle scrollable
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 .fixed {
        height: calc(100vh - 130px);// 130px is the extra space set it accordingly if you didn't find aligned divs
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

Comment: with this solution, I compulsory need to scroll cursor on middle section.. this is not exactly what I want.. Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

add one custom class with your list-group like `myStickyListGroup`.

now make css to that class as I applied in css code below.

and then make script to update your list's `top` position by using javascript which you can see below.

I hope this will work for you and I have to inform you that you have to make changes in script conditions as per your requirement in your page.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.myStickyListGroup').css({'top': windowTop});
});
```

```css
.myStickyListGroup{
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Offline</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body style="background-color: #eceef4">
      <div class="container" style="position:relative; margin-top:100px">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 d-none d-lg-block">
               <ul class="list-group myStickyListGroup shadow bg-white rounded">
                  <li class="list-group-item rounded">List Item 1</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item rounded">List Item 2</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item rounded">List Item 3</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item rounded">List Item 4</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item rounded">List Item 5</li>
               </ul>
               <hr class="d-sm-none">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
               <div class="card shadow bg-white rounded">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                     <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
                     <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div id="mdb-lightbox-ui"></div>
                        <!-- <div class="mdb-lightbox"> -->
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(145).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(145).jpg" class="img-fluid circle">
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(150).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(150).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(152).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(152).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(42).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(42).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(151).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(151).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(40).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(40).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(148).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(148).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(147).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(147).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(149).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(149).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <!-- </div> -->
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="card shadow bg-white rounded">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                     <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
                     <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div id="mdb-lightbox-ui"></div>
                        <!-- <div class="mdb-lightbox"> -->
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(145).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(145).jpg" class="img-fluid circle">
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(150).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(150).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(152).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(152).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(42).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(42).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(151).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(151).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(40).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(40).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(148).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(148).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(147).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(147).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <figure class="col-4">
                           <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(149).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                           <img alt="picture" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(149).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                           </a>
                        </figure>
                        <!-- </div> -->
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <hr class="d-sm-none">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 d-none d-lg-block">
               <ul class="list-group myStickyListGroup shadow bg-white rounded">
                  <li class="list-group-item rounded">List Item 1</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item rounded">List Item 2</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item rounded">List Item 3</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item rounded">List Item 4</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item rounded">List Item 5</li>
               </ul>
               <hr class="d-sm-none">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sry for late reply.. Yes sir, its working.. small changes are to be made.. as its shaking while scroll..

Comment: and i am not sir you can call me with my name.

Comment: I got answer..  by adding classes to other two section .sticky-top.. Thank you.. :)